# How to run multiple websites from one Django project on nginx and uwsgi

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi

How to run two web sites or subdomains of a site from a single Django code base.

Each Django app in the project can then power a website on a different domain, but all the apps can still share a single database with a single administrative interface.

I'm Deploying with uWSGI-Nginx-Django

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to deploy Django apps separately on uwsgi. An official site suggest to use [emperor mode](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Emperor.html). First you have to write [Upstart](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Upstart.html) script at `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf` like this,

```
# Emperor uWSGI script

description "uWSGI Emperor"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

# uwsgi location
#env UWSGI=/usr/bin/uwsgi
env UWSGI=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi

env LOGTO=<your log folder>

exec $UWSGI --master --die-on-term --emperor /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/ --pythonpath /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages --uid www-data --gid www-data --logto $LOGTO --enable-threads
```

In /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/, it'll contain your uwsgi configuration for each Django application. e.g. /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/app1.ini

Here's the sample configuration that I use.

```
[uwsgi]
; define variables to use in this script
; process name for easy identification in top
project = <project name>
base_dir = /<your base directory>/
chdir = %(base_dir)

pythonpath = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

http = 0.0.0.0:8000

uid = www-data
gid = www-data

procname = %(project)

; Enable master mode
; uWSGI’s built-in prefork+threading multi-worker management mode, activated by flicking the master switch on. For ; all practical serving deployments it’s not really a good idea not to use master mode.
master = true
master = 1

; run master process as root
master-as-root = true

; This value needs to be tuned
workers = 4

; Create pid file for easier process management
pidfile=/run/uwsgi/%(project).pid

# Specify your Django app here
module = mysite.wsgi:application
#or
#wsgi-file = %(base_dir)/<your wsgi file>.py

log-reopen = true
logto = /<your log directory>

chmod-socket = 666

vacuum = True
enable-threads = True

# Enable stats. View using `uwsgitop localhost:4000`
stats = :4000

; unix socket (referenced in nginx configuration)
socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
```

To run two web sites or subdomains of a site from a single Django code base, you need to set your domain at server_name directive for each Django application
For example /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yourweb1.conf that's bind to DjangoApp1

```
server_name app1.yourweb.com
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yourweb2.conf that's bind to DjangoApp2

```
server_name app2.yourweb.com
```

[More information about deploying Django application with nginx](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)

Comment: We prefer it here if you can summarise the important parts in your answer rather than just providing a link because links go dead over time.  Feel free to edit your answer with the information.